# Can I make a DSN-less connection using pyodbc and mdbtools?

Tags: odbc, mdbtools

I've tried the following:

```
>>> import pyodbc

>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver="MDB", database="SohabeD51.mdb")
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC]Could not find DSN in
                connect string (1) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

Connecting to a database using a DSN entry works fine, but I'd like to supply a database in the code.

Comment: Can you share how you were able to connect using the DSN entry? What was your connection string for pyodbc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but actually (0.7.1) MDBTools DOES support DSN-less connections. The syntax for the connection string is something like

```
DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=/path/to/your/file.mdb;UID=;PWD=;
```

You can download it from Github and compile it to ensure you are up to date:

https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools

Comment: Not tested, as this is an old question.

Answer (score 2):

No. Mdbtools 0.5 don't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings